# How do I copy files I downloaded from the wayback machine to my new site?

Tags: plugins, migration, plugin-recommendation

I had a drupal site for many years that crashed. I thought I lost all my files, but I was able to download an enormous amount from the Wayback Machine. Now the question is, how do I move those files and get the old articles live on my WordPress site? I did find a plugin for a Drupal to WordPress migration, but it seems to need live sites. Since I only have the files, what should I do?

[image]

Comment: There's a company called archivarix that seems to pull the data from the wayback machine in a way that can be read by CMS. That's what I'm using to get the data back

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you can do that. WP files are stored in the database. The Wayback machine is just a generated version of the files.

You need the database. Your hosting place might have a database backup, though. If you can get a backup copy of the database, you can use that in a new Drupal install, then export/import into WP.

Maybe.

Otherwise you could 'scrape' the Wayback site for the pages, but that will just give you a static site.

Comment: There's a company called archivarix that seems to pull the data from the wayback machine in a way that can be read by CMS. That's what I'm using to get the data back

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, you should definitely get in touch ASAP with the support department of your hosting provider. They may have taken regular backups automatically, and could potentially restore your drupal website to it's former pre-crash self.

However, if all that you have is copies of the pages (from the Wayback Machine) then you would need to "massage" that set of pages/data into a format that can be readily uploaded to your new Wordpress website via something like this plugin;

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/

To use this particular plugin, you would first have to create a CSV file that contains all the data that you want to upload. You should be able to use any spreadsheet program or cloud app to create this file. Once you have entered all the data into the spreadsheet you can save/export it as a CSV file.

An example of a spreadsheet is here;

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_szbefwadOTU16cl90OXFDT00/view

[image: Ultimate CSV Importer example spreadsheet for Posts data]

NB: Be prepared to do a lot of hours work entering your old data!